# flutter percentage of number data in Text widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to calculate percent of double type data in text widget.

```
Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 1, 5, 10),
      child: Text(    data[numberdata].toString(), //I want to calculate 5 percent of this numberdata



    style:  GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 18 , textStyle: 
            TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tricky to be sure what you are after. But my best guess is:

```
Text((data[numberdata]*0.05).toString()),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...
child: Text(double.tryParse(data[numberdata].toString())*(5/100).toString()),
or
child: Text((double.tryParse(data[numberdata].toString())*0.5).toString()),
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to multiple it by the percent
For example in your text widget replace the code with

```
  ${data[numberdata] * 0.05}
```

This will show 5 percent of the value.

Answer (score 0):

> // let us say your number was 100 :

---

- **if you want to add a increment + %5 to your number use this :**

Text((data[numberdata]*1.05).toString()),

```
// this will give you 105 .
```

- **if you want to add a decrement - %5 to your number use this** :

Text((data[numberdata]*0.95).toString()),

```
// this will give you 95 .
```